# Galerkin method and weak-$*$ convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I came accros the following statement :

If $\lbrace u_{n}\rbrace$ and $\lbrace u_{nx}\rbrace$ are bounded sequences in $L^{\infty}([0,T];L^{2}(0,1))$, where $u_{n}\in \mathcal{C}^{1}([0,T];H_{0}^{3}(0,1))$ for all $n$, then there exists a subsequence $\lbrace u_{n_{k}} \rbrace$ that converges in the weak star topology of $L^{\infty}L^{2}$ to a function $u\in \mathcal{C}([0,T];H^{2}_{0}(0,1))$.

The context here is Galerkin method for proving well-posedness of a PDE. The $u_{n}$'s are the approximate weak solutions, and the limit is the weak solution of the original PDE.

My question is : How is this obtained ? I know that bounded sequences in $L^{\infty}$ admit weakly-star convergent subsequences, but i do not know how to obtain the regularity of the limit. Like, why we moved from $H^3$ to $H^2$, and from $C^1$ to only $C$ ?

Comment: When you have some functions $f_n$ converging to some other function $f$, the rule of thumb is: any bound on $f_n$ which is UNIFORM in $n$ can be also transferred on $f$ (e.g. via Fatou's lemma). Here the $C^1H^3$ bound is not uniform in $n$ (to what I undertand), so you can't expect your limit to be that regular. But you can still hope that $u$ and $u_x$ are in $L^\infty L^2$, which is in fact true. I don't see how to upgrade this to $C H^2$, you probably have some other bound hidden somewhere in the book/paper on the second derivatives of $u_n$

Comment: I suspect two thing might be happening: you either have some additional uniform bound coming from the PDE on $u_n$, or you have proved that $u$ satisfies your PDE, so you prove the bounds on $u$ directly. But it is hard to judge. In any case, if your bound is not uniform in $n$, there is not much you can do to transfer regularity form $u_n$ to $u$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @LorenzoPompili . The statement comes from this paper http://www.internonlinearscience.org/upload/papers/IJNS%20Vol%2014%20No%203%20Paper%2015%20Boundary%20Control%20of%20the%20Korteweg-de%20Vries-Burgers%20Equation%20and%20its.pdf in the well-posedness part. Here I understand from a priori estimates that the $L^{\infty} L^2$ bound is uniform wrt to $n$. I will try to see now what happens for regularity ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand all the details here. But it seems to me that the equation is linear with dissipation, etc.,, I am confident the estimates comes from the fact that $u$ is a solution to the PDE. It probably holds a similar a priori bound for the functions $u_n$ as well. In any case, it is clear that $u_n$ being in $C^1H^3$ is something you can't use directly to obtain higher regularity for $u$

Comment: Yes, for the galerkin approximation he replaces the nonlinearity $uu_{x}$ with $\lambda u_{x}$. I will try to see this in more details, thank's !